# Is new object creation necessary with BigDecimal?

Tags: java, algorithms, performance, numeric-precision

**Problem description:**

I am running performance test of calculation of `PI` number with `primitives` and with `BigDecimal` class.

Calculation of `PI` with primitives is around 5-6 times faster than the same algorithm, but with `BigDecimal` class.

I see a problem with creation of `new` BigDecimal object in the `for` loop, when adding values - see [full code](https://pastebin.com/wr8qjzCY) with line marked with comment.

**Findings:**

`BigDecimal` class has `3` methods which allows for addition

```
1.    public BigDecimal add(BigDecimal augend)
2.    public BigDecimal add(BigDecimal augend, MathContext mc)
3.    public static BigDecimal valueOf(long val)
```

When using `BigDecimal#valueOf` method, the calculation time was even bigger than with `new` object creation.

Thus, the question - is it possible to increase performance of the calculation when using `BigDecimal` objects?

Comment: It seems your code is using the Gregory series for calculating Pi, which is a very slow converging method. That is probably where you should look at if you want to increase the performance. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html for some ideas, or even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-value-of-%CF%80

Answer (score 2):

`BigDecimal` is based on a decimal representation of fractional numbers, and that's not the natural representation for a digital computer (Java is lacking something like BigBinaryFractional). On the other hand, `double` is a binary datatype directly supported by all modern CPUs. That's the first part of the performance difference.

In the lines

```
        double i2 = 4 * (pow / i1);
        pi = pi.add(new BigDecimal(i2));
```

you mix double and BigDecimal representations, needing conversions that further slow down the code.

And of course, double is a primitive, whereas BigDecimal is a reference type, so there's an overhead of object creation and later garbage collection.

So, I'm positively surprised that the difference is only a factor of 5.

Comment: true, but if there is a need to calculate longer PI value than 20 decimal digits (java.lang.Math.PI), we must use `BigDecimal` as `double` has limited precision. So in the program I used `BigDecimal`, unfortunatelly with lose of performance. So I do appericiate your response, but I do consider the question as not answered yet.

Comment: @DevDio You didn't use `BigDecimal` very much. Try `BigDecimal pow = BigDecimal.ONE.negate().pow(i); BigDecimal i1 = two.multiply(new BigDecimal(i)).add(BigDecimal.ONE); BigDecimal i2 = four.multiply(pow).divide(i1, MathContext.DECIMAL128); pi = pi.add(i2);` (with two and four being `BigDecimal` 2 and 4)

Comment: Note that `MathContext.UNLIMITED` results in "ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.", which is kind-of what we wanted here :(